# LU decomposition for non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the LU decomposition for a given matrix $A$:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 4 & -2\\
-1 & 1 & -4 & -5 & 3\\
2 & -2 & 5 & 9 & -5
\end{bmatrix}

$r_1 + r_2$ and $-2r_1 + r_3$ yields

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 4 & -2\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

$-r_2 + r_3$ yields

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 4 & -2\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -2
\end{bmatrix}

$2r_2 + r_3$ yields

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 4 & -2\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

This is our $U.$

Hence our lower triangular matrix, $L$ is 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

However, from our last row operation, our $L$ is now
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & -2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

However, when I do $L \cdot U$ I get
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 4 & -2\\
-1 & 1 & -4 & -5 & 3\\
2 & -2 & 8 & 10 & -6
\end{bmatrix}

Note that the last three entries in the third row are all off by $1$, so obviously I messed with my $L$ a bit in the last row, to no avail though. Any help?

Comment: your $2r_2+r_3$ is neither correct nor necessary.

Comment: Mind explaining why it's not necessary? Why don't I need use elimination to make the $a_{3,4}$ a zero?

Comment: Umm, check out what happens in that step - the third column, in particular!

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks.